# In drupal 8, how do i access the markup of a media entity?

Tags: drupal-8

I am in mymodule_node_view_alter because i want to conditionally unset one of the fields of a node.
I kint($build).
The field i am interested in is a media entity (media image). 
How'd I get to the markup of a media entity?
I brows through output of kint() but never see anything like a link or a uri for that media file?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the media target id from the $build then you have to load Media by target_id and then you will get the uri & URL of the media file.